# How to add additional clock in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, clock

It was quite simple in Ubuntu 16.04 to add additional clock from different time zone. But I am not sure how to add in 18.04, I checked the settings but it doesn't have any options. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a programm called `gnome-clocks`, where you can add
timezones.

```
sudo apt install gnome-clocks
```

[image: gnome-clocks]
It will listen these timezones under your calendar.

Comment: This combined with the Top Bar Clocks extension did exactly what I wanted.