# How to add Cities time in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I need to have other cities' time on Ubuntu 18.04, like on Ubuntu 16.04
Time & Date settings, but I can find no information on how to do this.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: similar question ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069680/how-to-add-additional-clock-in-ubuntu-18-04